# Css jquery Combobox

Tags: jquery, css, combobox

I am trying to create a combo box with css and jquery. I will be having 3 items and I need help on selecting items in combobox and showing up the selected item. Any help would be highly appreciated. My complete code is

http://jsfiddle.net/vmCBJ/

```
 $(function () {
        $('#clickIcon').click(function() {

        });
        $("ul.dropdown li").click(function () {
            $(this).addClass("hover");
            $('ul:first', this).css('visibility', 'visible');

        }, function () {

            $(this).removeClass("hover");
            $('ul:first', this).css('visibility', 'hidden');

        });

        $("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &amp;amp;amp;raquo; ");

    });


<div id="page-wrap">
    <span>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Cannot</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Can</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Must</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </span>
    <span id="clickIcon" style="background-color: gray;padding-left: 5px;font-weight: 900;">
        V
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no combo box in the code - just a list

Comment: I am trying to make it look like a combobox with list. I am trying to get combobox functionality to list.

Comment: Usham, you mentioned "showing up the selected item", Where you want to show the selected item? If you explain little bit more that will helpful to resolve the issue

Comment: Sorry. He is how I need. Just like a combo box selection, If I select one item in list it should be shown as selected item and other two should be in list. Just similar to a combobox items selection.

Comment: Usham you mean if user select "Can", "Can" should be the top and "Can not" should be the third option like that.

Comment: If you could use Jquery UI, it would be easy for you. check [this](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution... http://jsfiddle.net/K2ndZ/

I've rebuilt it so the functionality should be fairly clear. You should be aware, however, that this solution will fall apart if the user doesn't have javascript on their browser... would a drop down menu not be a better option?

HTML

```
<div class="combobox">
    <div class="selector">Please select</div>
    <ul>
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.combobox {cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;}
.combobox .selector{border:1px solid #cccccc;padding: 2px 5px}
.combobox ul {padding:0;margin:0;display:inline-block;border:1px solid #eeeeee;background-color:#cccccc;}
.combobox li {padding: 2px 5px}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.combobox ul').hide();
    $('.combobox').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('ul').stop().slideDown();
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('ul').stop().slideUp();
        }
    );
    $('.combobox li').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('.combobox').find('.selector').text($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow isn't made so we can write the code for you. You need to do some research yourself. You are gonna need a whole lot more than just showing which item in the list is "active" to make a proper working combobox. By the way combobox isn't the right word for what you made. This is more like a custom dropdown.

I updated your code (with complete not to use in a live environment code) to point you in a direction. http://jsfiddle.net/vmCBJ/1/

What I did:

```
    $(".sub_menu a").click(function () {
        var currentItem = $(this).text();
        $active = $('.dropdown a').first();
        $(this).text($active.text());
        $active.text(currentItem);

        return false;
    });
```

Catch the click event in the submenu. Save the text from the "clicked" item in a variable. Find the element that is "active" (the one outside of your submenu) and swap the text to the one that you clicked with "active".

This doesn't really make up for a good combobox though :)

Comment: I think Usham has made reasonable efforts to solve this for himself - he just seems to have hit a bit of a sticking point.